# 400 error when querying microsoft graph via javascript sdk

Tags: javascript, microsoft-graph-api

Hi I am getting a 404 error when querying any api endpoint. Im trying to get calendar events from my company. I have added the following to the application scopes. Anyone know why this might be occurring? thanks. Im using pretty much this example as a base here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/rest/javascript-tutorial

## scopes in developer portal

[image: in graph api]

## scopes

```
var scopes = 'openid profile User.Read Mail.Read Calendars.Read Calendars.Read.Shared';
```

## my resulting 404 error

[image: image of issue]

Comment: Can you include the code you're using to obtain your token? Also, have you attempted to replicate this issue using Graph Explorer? That would help narrow down if the issue is in your code/token or in the data graph is accessing.

Answer (score 0):

Below is [Graph API Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) link for Microsoft Graph API

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer?request=me%2Fcalendar%2Fevents%3F%24top%3D10%26%24select%3Dsubject%26%24orderBy%3DcreatedDateTime&method=GET&version=v1.0

Below is the response from the API you've added in 404 error image which is working as expected with same url -

[image: api response]

Comment: Hmm yes I get the same error there. Is there something I have to enable on my company’s side? Or is there a possibility if it’s a company , they’re server might not support this api? Thanks

Comment: @c.m it's working for me, you can try out by clicking url, no there will not be any issue from your company side, btw what are you using for making this request, rest call or sdk?

Comment: I tried the sdk and just a rest call, but the 404 error still happens. It also doesn’t work so on explorer . Only getting my bio works as a call. Is there a permissions thing I need to set  on my windows account?